# Extjs stacked chart bar with dynamic group members

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

In example
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/charts/StackedBar.html

```
data: [
    {year: 2005, comedy: 34000000, action: 23890000, drama: 18450000, thriller: 20060000},
    {year: 2006, comedy: 56703000, action: 38900000, drama: 12650000, thriller: 21000000},
    {year: 2007, comedy: 42100000, action: 50410000, drama: 25780000, thriller: 23040000},
    {year: 2008, comedy: 38910000, action: 56070000, drama: 24810000, thriller: 26940000}
]
```

how to make same chart with this data:

```
data: [
    {name: comedy, y2005: 34000000, y2006: 56703000, y2007: 42100000, y2008: 38910000},
    {name: action, y2005: 23890000, y2006: 38900000, y2007: 50410000, y2008: 56070000},
    {name: drama, y2005: 18450000, y2006: 12650000, y2007: 25780000, y2008: 24810000},
    {name: thtiller, y2005: 20060000, y2006: 21000000, y2007: 23040000, y2008: 26940000}
]
```

?

Comment: I am afraid that this is not possible. You will have to transform your data to structure as is in example.

Comment: @Akatum i can't. value of 'name' not permanent, but y2005..y2008 permanent. model:  `fields: [{ name: 'name', type: 'auto' },{name: 'y2005', type: 'auto},...,{name: 'y2008', type: 'auto'}]`